# Wrong offset retrieval from Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, offset

I am trying to write some Avro data to Kafka and use it as an offset for reading the records from the database. So I do not want to read all records after each data processing stage I save offset to Kafka and then start from it my data reading process. I have defined read the data method and the latest offset retrieval methods for that. The problem is that when I add new data for the 1st time and save offset it is not retrieved properly or something like that. When I add the data the 2nd time the data is retrieved starting from the previous offset and not the current one. Expected result:

The first batch of data includes primary keys 1-20, offset the record data for primary key 20, data is retrieved starting from 1.
The second batch of data includes primary keys 21-30, offset the record data for primary key 30, data is retrieved starting from 20 (previous offset).
The third batch of data includes primary keys 31-40, offset the record data for primary key 40, data is retrieved starting from 30 (previous offset).
and so on.

Actual behavior looks like this:

The first batch of data includes primary keys 1-20, offset the record data for primary key 20, data is retrieved starting from 1.
The second batch of data includes primary keys 20-30, offset the record data for primary key 30, no data is retrieved.
The third batch of data includes primary keys 31-40, offset the record data for primary key 40, data is retrieved starting from 20 (???).

So what could be the reason for it? Is there a problem with some Kafka configuration or overall code logic?

This is the way I retrieve the latest offset from Kafka

And this is the code for reading the state I saved to Kafka:

```
def getLatestOffset() = {
    val kafkaProperties = new Properties()
    kafkaProperties.putAll(kafkaParams)

    val topicAndPartition = new TopicPartition(kafkaTopic, 0)
    val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String,GenericRecord](kafkaProperties)
    consumer.subscribe(java.util.Arrays.asList(kafkaTopic))

    val consumerRecords = consumer
      .poll(10000)
      .records(kafkaTopic)
      .asScala
      .toList

    val partitionsAssigned = consumer.assignment()
    val endOffset = consumer.endOffsets(partitionsAssigned)
      .get(topicAndPartition)

    endOffset
  }

  def readComplexStateFromKafka(sparkSession: SparkSession, dayColumn: String, endingOffset: Long) = {
    logger.debug(s"Reading from Kafka topic: $kafkaTopic")
    val offsetRanges = Array(
      OffsetRange(kafkaTopic, 0, endingOffset-1, endingOffset)
    )

    val dataRDD = KafkaUtils.createRDD(
      sparkSession.sparkContext,
      sparkAppConfig.kafkaParams.asJava,
      offsetRanges,
      LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
    )

    val genericRecordsValues = dataRDD
      .map(record =>
        record
          .value()
          .asInstanceOf[GenericRecord]
      )

    val genericRecordsFields = genericRecordsValues
      .map(record =>
          (record.get("table_name").toString,
          record.get("code").toString,
          new Timestamp(record.get(dayColumn).asInstanceOf[Long]).toString)
      )

    genericRecordsFields.first()
  }
```

Kafka parameters look like this:

```
  bootstrapServers = "kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:9092"
  schemaRegistryUrl = "http://cp-schema-registry:8081"
  topic = "tableName_offsets"
  keyDeserializer = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"
  valueDeserializer = "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer"
  keySerializer = "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
  valueSerializer = "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
  clientId = "table_state"
  groupId = "avro_data"
  autoOffsetReset = "latest"
  enableAutoCommit = true
  auto.commit.interval.ms = 10000
```

Comment: If you're reading data from a database, have you considered using Kafka Connect instead of writing this for yourself? https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-ny19/no-more-silos-integrating-db-into-apache-kafka goes into the options available.

Comment: Well, my colleagues had some issues with it and proposed to stick with basic Kafka for now,

Comment: With respect, I would suggest troubleshooting those issues and using Kafka Connect - than trying to re-invent the wheel :) Feel free to post another question on the apache-kafka-connect tag with details of the issues encountered and I can help out there. Fundamtentally, Kafka Connect (which is part of Apache Kafka) is _specifically for_ integrating systems such as databases into Kafka.